# PHP using a variable in a variable name

Tags: php, variables

I have two preexisting variables:

`$side` (which is either F or B)
and
`$plate` (which is a 3 digit number)

I am trying to build two arrays called

`$sidecountF`
and 
`$sidecountB`

using the following code:

```
$sidecount{$side}[$plate] = 1;
```

assuming $side is F and $plate is 200, I'm hoping that the end result is that

```
$sidecountF[200] = 1;
```

I am, at the beginning, declaring `sidecountF` and `sidecountB` as arrays with

```
$sidecountF = array();
$sidecountB = array();
```

So now I'm stumped.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Your code appears to be correct.

Comment: sorry, i left a sentence out of the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
${"sidecount$side"} = array();
```

But you're better off using arrays:

```
$sidecount = array("F" = array(), "B" => array());
$sidecount[$side][$plate] = /* ... */
```

Comment: Agreed with array using! Gives much more flexibility in the end... At least it always happens with my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_blank = array(
    'sidecount' . $side => array()
);

extract($_blank);
```

this would be another way of doing it, it also is not bound to creating 1 variable with `${""}` you can create several variables at once.