# Varying variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I have 10 variables: `$c1=a;` through `$c10=j;`
I also have a variable `$i=1;`

I'm now wondering if there is any way possible that I can write `abcdefghij` on the page without having to write `echo $c1.$c2.$c3.$c4.$c5.$c6.$c7.$c8.$c9.$c10;`

I've been trying:

```
if ($i<11){
echo "$c$i";
$i++;
}
```

But of course, that does not work, and almost every other combination I try just outputs plain text onto the screen. Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you use an array? Makes more sense... and then it's just `echo implode('', $array);`.

Comment: There is a way, but can't you just use an array instead?

Comment: For the project I'm working on I cannot =)

Comment: Homework? Or why? Why restrict yourself for no reason?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP using a variable in a variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522868/php-using-a-variable-in-a-variable-name)

Comment: I'm doing a project on arrays. This helps a lot to understand why they were created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
if ($i<11) {
  echo ${'c'.$i}; // will be evaluated to $c1, $c2, ...
  $i++;
}
```

But as stated in the comments you should stick to arrays!

Comment: just have to say: *man, this is ugly coding!* (but yes, it does the job)

Comment: I completely agree! But it's a feature of PHP and it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Given your requirements, you can use variable variables:

```
<?php
//Your variables
$c1 = 'a';
$c2 = 'b';
$c3 = 'c';
$c4 = 'd';
$c5 = 'e';
$c6 = 'f';
$c7 = 'g';
$c8 = 'h';
$c9 = 'i';
$c10 = 'j';

$i = 1;

//Loop through
for ($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++){
    $var = 'c' . $i;
    echo $$var; //use "variable" variables
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$i = 1;
while($i<=3){
   $b = "c{$i}";
   echo $$b;
   $i++;
}
```

thanks